# Mesh size of the silica gel

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, chromatography

What does the Mesh in the mesh size of silica gel that is used for various chromatography techniques mean?

Answer (score 2):

Mesh is a unit representing the grain-size distribution of a material. So it represents either the opening of the mesh, or the number of grain per surface unit depending on what you are considering.

You can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_%28scale%29) the conversion in grain size and surface unit related to the "Mesh".